# Mixpanel with Turbo Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mixpanel, turbo-rails

I'm getting the following error while trying to use the Turbo Rails link:

`Mixpanel error: The Mixpanel library has already been downloaded at least once. Ensure that the Mixpanel code snippet only appears once on the page (and is not double-loaded by a tag manager) in order to avoid errors.`

My layout code is:

```
<HTML>
<head>

<%= mixpanel_code %>

</head>
<body>
...
<%= link_to "Settings", my_settings_path %>
...

</body>
</HTML>
```

This issue doesn’t exist if Turbo Rails is disabled.

What’s the correct way to use mixpanel with Turbo?

Thanks